# Conditions must satisfy $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ so that its Taylor series converge to f itself.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a doubt.

What conditions must satisfy $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ so that its Taylor series 
converge to f itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is exactly your question, but I think you look for $f$ being an analytic function. For example $$e^x= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ is analytic.

Comment: But one usual definition of "analytic" is "representable by a power series." So this seems circular.

Comment: It's true that that is the definition of analytic.  I don't think there is a "nice" criterion for analyticity in real functions.  For example, even a smooth function needn't be analytic.

Comment: @StrangerLoop See the post linked above, under the question.